# Delete CCK fields that are flagged as "inactive"

Tags: 6, entities, features

With D6, I have a Feature that defines a content type and a number of fields. It's currently deployed and living happily on Production servers. My Feature is now changing, and some of the old CCK fields will no longer be needed. Any updates must be done *programmatically*. Here's what I plan to do:

- Removed the fields from my Feature export
- Deploy the new Feature, which will leave the CCK field & data in the DB, but flag the CCK field as "inactive"
- Run a migration script to move the old field data into the appropriate place
- Delete the CCK fields from the database for good

It's the last step where I'm uncertain how to best proceed. I read (somewhere?) that content_field_instance_delete() can only be used to process "active" fields. Can I just safely delete the column from the appropriate content_type_* table?